# Xcode 13 UIButton state config not showing up in interface builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode13

After updating to Xcode 13, when I add an UIButton to my Storyboard, the State Config no longer shows up as an option.

[image: Screenshot showing missing State Config]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found out that with Xcode 13 you have to change the style of the UIButton from plain to default. The default when you insert a UIButton in your Storyboard is NOT default, but plain. Changing to default makes the State Config show back up!

[image: Screenshot showing style selector]

Comment: Thank you! This also explains why the title "Button" would appear at run time, even though I thought I deleted the text in the storyboard. I needed to switch to Default, and then I could delete the "Button" title.

Comment: @bugloaf, yes it does indeed! I still don't understand why they changed the default style of the button to not be the default style